# JMeter 500--Internal Server Error

Tags: jmeter

When I test my application with JMeter on weblogic server for one user I get:

```
Error 500--Internal Server Error From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer
Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
10.5.1 500 Internal Server Error 
The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.
```

This error present only on one page which is in the middle of the test application. I have Cookie Manager to get cookie id from response and cached all url parameter which is changing dynamically.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem "Internal Server Error" i.e, Response code 500. I cleared the results and added HTTP Cookie Manager to the thread and executed successfully the Test Plan.

Here you, my Result without HTTP Cookie Manager
Thread Name: NEW EMP Registration Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2013-04-09 15:56:43 IST
Load time: 112
Latency: 112
Size in bytes: 5163
Headers size in bytes: 240
Body size in bytes: 4923
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: 500
Response message: Internal Server Error

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 09 Apr 2013 10:26:42 GMT
Content-Length: 4923

After adding HTTP cookie manager

Sample Start: 2013-04-09 16:00:19 IST
Load time: 439
Latency: 430
Size in bytes: 195638
Headers size in bytes: 223
Body size in bytes: 195415
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 0
Response code: 200
Response message: OK

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 09 Apr 2013 10:30:19 GMT
Content-Length: 195415

Hope this will help you :)

Fingers-cross

Answer (score 0):

Internal Server Error (500) means there is something wrong with your server code - probably an uncaught exception. Try to debug your server code when it is being accessed by JMeter.

Comment: I use weblogic server from oracle. Probably you think to debug the web application? Is it possible this error to be generated from web application?

Answer (score 0):

My script is only getting executed for recorded data and not parameterized one, though in Tree Listener ->Request-> HTTP is displaying parameterized data from CSV file, but post execution record are getting updated only for recorded data, is it because scenario is based on ajax requests. Please do let me know in case elaboration required.